# df.sort_values is not sorting table (python/pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, sorting

df.sort_values in pandas is not working for me, the same df is getting returned without being sorted.

```
def findExpression(transType, sortColName=None):
    global df

    if transType == 'sortAscending':
        df.sort_values(sortColName)
        return df

print(findExpression('sortAscending', sortColName='col9'))

Actual Output:
    col1  col2        col3        col4      col5  col6   col7   col8  col9
0  12345  12ab  2008-11-22  2009-11-22     beans  25.0  715.0   True    10
1  67890  34cd  2009-12-23  2010-12-23  catzilla  25.0   75.0  False     6
2  13579  56ef  2010-01-24  2011-01-24     boots  25.0   75.0   True     5
3  24680  78gh  2011-02-25  2012-02-25   whitish  25.0   75.0   True     6
4  12560  90ij  2012-03-26  2013-03-26      coco  25.0   75.0   True     1

Expected:
    col1  col2        col3        col4      col5  col6   col7   col8  col9
0  12560  90ij  2012-03-26  2013-03-26      coco  25.0   75.0   True     1
1  13579  56ef  2010-01-24  2011-01-24     boots  25.0   75.0   True     5
2  24680  78gh  2011-02-25  2012-02-25   whitish  25.0   75.0   True     6
3  67890  34cd  2009-12-23  2010-12-23  catzilla  25.0   75.0  False     6
4  12345  12ab  2008-11-22  2009-11-22     beans  25.0  715.0   True    10
```

Comment: sort_values is not an inplace method, you need to either add a parameter in sort_values `inplace=True` or re-assign using `df = df.sort_values(sortColName)`.

Comment: Or `return df.sort_values('sortColName')`.

Comment: Do we have to have people ask a question every time they forget to assign a result back? Nothing in pandas operates in-place by default; some methods have the inplace option you need to set. Others don't even have that. The only exception is `set_axis` whose behaviour is about to be deprecated. I think it's time to address these ridiculous "help me I haven't read the documentation" questions.

Comment: @cs95  How do you propse we "address these ridiculous ... questions"?

Comment: @ScottBoston The same way I usually address them... with a self-answered post. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most pandas function don't modify the elements directly but return a modified copy of it. If you want to modify the object directly you have to add the option `inplace = True` :

```
df.sort_values(sortColName, inplace = True)
```

which is the same as doing :

```
df = df.sort_values(sortColName)
```